# What is normal fluctuation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

I was reading Statistical Mechanics (second edition) by Kerson Huang. On page 146, after equation 7.14, there is a reference to normal fluctuation. What is it?

Here is the relevant part from the book.

$<H^2> - <H>^2  = kT^2C_v$

Since $<H> \varpropto N$ and $C_v \varpropto N$, the above given equation is a normal fluctuation.

Comment: Could you expand on the context in which it is mentioned (for example by quoting the entire sentence)? Possibly, someone who doesn't have the book available will be able to answer the question then.

Comment: He probably means that the fluctuations of the relevant quantity (here the energy) follow a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). Actually, here he seems happy with the weaker claim that the scale of these fluctuations are of the right order (the variance is of order $N$).

Comment: @SebastianRiese I have added the relevant part from the book as suggested.